# Bullet list with more than three levels

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown

When reading the Pandoc [documentation](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#block-content-in-list-items) and the R-markdown [cheat sheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/rmarkdown-cheatsheet.pdf) with bullet lists, it seems that is only possible to have three symbols to be used in a bullet list: `*`, `+`, or `-`.

Does this imply that on R-markdown, you are only allowed to have, at most, three depth levels in a bullet list? My intended usage is on a document made with Bookdown.

Comment: Nop. You could have more than three levels. Try it out. I just checked for up to 6 levels. However,  in the default HTML or Word templates there is only a limited number of symbols, so symbols for deeper levels get repeated. Only the default pdf/latex template allows for a maximum of 4 levels.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @stefan . So it would be repeating symbols on different identations then?

Comment: Yep. However, I would guess (or I'm pretty sure) that you could change that by providing a customized template which defines more and/or different symbols for each level.